# IText7: Creating Highlight for an PdfImageXObject

Tags: java, itext7

We converted our documents to PDF from tiff.  This created PdfImageXObjects within the resulting PDF.  The users markup the PDFs with using software provided by our document management system client.  The markups are stored outside of the PDF itself so they are really just screen overlays.  My problem is that when I attempt to merge the markups with the PDFs the highlights are dull since they must be transparent to show the text underneath.  One option is to extract PdfImageXObjects as bitmaps and convert the b/w images to RGB and perform a bitwise operation to replace the whitespace and not the text, a time consuming prospect.  Is there a way do this that is less time and resource intensive?

Comment: You can use image masks to achieve your goal

Comment: Or instead of alpha transparency use the blend mode **Multiply**.